# AngularJS Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, debugging, syntax-error

This code is causing an error in the developer console:

```
$scope.AddCandidatesToCompannies = function()
{
    console.table($scope.candidates);
    Object.entries($scope.candidates).forEach(candidate =>
    {
        candidate.jobs.forEach(job =>
        {
            var company_id = job['company_id'];

            Object.entries($scope.companies).forEach(company =>
            {
                if (company['company_id'] == company_id)
                {
                    console.log('match'); 
                };
            });
        });
    });
};   // AddCandidatesToCompannies()
```

`$scope.candidates` ***DOES*** contain data, and it ***is*** an object; it's quite complex, so I won't clutter the question with it, but her is an overview pic

[image]

The statement `Object.entries($scope.candidates).forEach(candidate =>` gives

> angular.min.js:83 TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
>       at mapController.js:138
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at a.$scope.AddCandidatesToCompannies (mapController.js:136)
>       at $scope.ProcessSearchResults (mapController.js:161)
>       at C (angular.min.js:91)
>       at C (angular.min.js:91)
>       at angular.min.js:92
>       at h.$eval (angular.min.js:100)
>       at h.$digest (angular.min.js:98)
>       at h.$apply (angular.min.js:101)
>       at f (angular.min.js:66)
>       at K (angular.min.js:70)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.y.onreadystatechange (angular.min.js:71)

Can anyone see what I am doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.entries return an arrays in an array with then key, value pairs.
Looks like you want to have a function like 
`Object.values($scope.candidates)`

Example:

```
Object.entries($scope.candidates) == [[45,{candidate_id:45}],[46,{candidate_id:46}]]
Object.values($scope.candidates) == [{candidate_id:45}, {candidate_id: 46}]
```